# How to deal with the different type of errors that returns from the cloud function?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, dialogflow-es

I have written the cloud functions which sends the response either with the statuscode 200 or 400 but sometimes I am getting this error

Function execution took 219 ms, finished with status: 'connection error'
Error: function crashed out of request scope Function invocation was interrupted.

So the problem is I need to know send this error message with some statuscode as the response of the cloud function.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const dialogflow = require('dialogflow');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const Firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
const firestore = new Firestore();
admin.initializeApp();
var db = admin.firestore();
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
var UID = new Object();

exports.fulfillmenttext = functions.https.onRequest((req,res) =>{ 
    const answer1 = req.body.Text;
    const uid = answer1.substring(0,28);
    const answer = answer1.substring(28);
    const sessionId = uid;
    var count,questvalue;
    const promise = db.collection("***").doc('***').collection("**").doc("uid").get();
    promise.then(doc => {
        snapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            if (doc.exists) {
              count = doc.data().count;
                if(count == 1){
                    var updatequest = title[questvalue];
                    res.status(200).send({"question":updatequest,"question_number":questvalue});
                    return;
              }
              else{
                runSample();
              }
          } 
          else {
              console.log("No such document!");
          }
        });
      }).catch(function(error) {
          console.log("Error getting document:", error);
      });


    async function runSample() {
      const languageCode = 'en-US';
      const projectId = 'xxxxxxx';
      const credentials = {
        client_email: 'xxxxxxx',
        private_key:
          'xxxxxxx',
      };
      //Instantiate a DialogFlow client.
      const dialogflow = require('dialogflow');
      const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient({
        projectId,
        credentials,
      });
    // Define session path
      const sessionPath = sessionClient.sessionPath(projectId, sessionId);
      // The text query request.

        const request = {
            //session: context1,
            session: sessionPath,
            queryInput: {
              text: {
                text: answer,
                languageCode,
              },
            },
        };

      const responses =  await sessionClient.detectIntent(request);
      const result = responses[0].queryResult;
      let action = result.action; 
      if (result.intent) {
        const question = result.fulfillmentText;
        console.log("question is",question);
        const actionHandlers = {
            'early': () => {
                console.log('earlyaction1', action);
                let name1 = JSON.stringify(result.parameters.fields.Name.stringValue);
                name1 = name1.toString().replace(/"/g,"");
                var data1 = {
                    Name: name1
                };
                var setDoc1 = admin.firestore().collection('**').doc('uid').collection("***").doc('uid').collection('**').doc('**').update(data1);


            },

        };
        if (action === 'early') {
             console.log('1');
             actionHandlers[action]();
        }


        res.status(200).send({"question":result.fulfillmentText,"action":action,"question_number":title.indexOf(question)});
        } else {
          console.log(`  No intent matched.`);
          res.status(400).send({"action":"empty"});
      }
    } 

});
```

Answer (score 1):

That message is telling you that you have some async code that was still running after the function terminated normally by sending a response to the client.  That bit of async code crashed.  Since the function already terminated by sending a response, there's nothing you can do to send **another** response.  There can only be one response per function invocation.

What you'll have to do is review your code and make sure you're 1) handling promises correctly and 2) not intentionally trying to leave any work going after sending the response, since Cloud Functions does not support that.

Comment: Yep I have used async code and i tried with the using promises correctly but the issue still occurs. What I mean is do we send that connection error message as the response with statuscode.

Comment: Since we can't see your code, we have way of knowing for sure that everything is correct as you say.

Comment: Ok I have sent you the code once go through it.-  Doug Stevenson

Comment: You're not handling all the promises from the Firestore API calls correctly.

Comment: You're calling update on a Firestore document in runSample, but ignoring the promise it returns.

Comment: May I know where did I ignore the promise?

Comment: Doug stevenson- Continution to the previous comment you mean I should not use update query in the run sample i.e in this line -----> var setDoc1 = admin.firestore().collection('**').doc('uid').collection("***").doc('uid').collection('**').doc('**').update(data1);